# Calling a method of subclass through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Here is my superclass `Animal`

```
class Animal
{
   //Empty
}
```

My subclass `Tiger`

```
class Tiger extends Animal
{
    public static void TigerPrint()
    {     -------
        System.out.println("Tiger");
    }
    public void Run()
    {
         System.out.println("Tiger Running");
    }
}
```

Now I do,

```
  Animal a=new Tiger();
```

At **compile time** `a` would be an `Animal`.At **runtime** it would be `Tiger`.

So,I did

```
a.getClass().getMethod("TigerPrint").invoke(null);//WORKS
a.getClass().getMethod("Run").invoke(null);//NOT WORKING (NullPointerException)
```

How can I call the `Run` method of `subclass` through reflection.

Yes I can do

```
((Tiger)a).Run();
```

But how can i do that in reflection!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are invoking an instance method on a null instance - so it makes sense that you receive a NPE. Try this instead (passing an instance to the `invoke` method instead of `null`):

```
a.getClass().getMethod("Run").invoke(a);
```

Note: the first call worked because you can call a static method on a null instance without causing a NPE.

Comment: @Arpit You can comment here if you want - not sure how the chat works on SO to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices either make `run()` method static and remain with current call or change the current call to pass the object instance as assylias pointed.